# Excel cell addresses from Excel formula with EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, regex, epplus

I have application which read data from excel file including formula using EPPlus.
my routine extract cell address from formula.

few sample formula which my application can still parse using RegEx.

> a) (W2/R2)-1
> b) W23-U23

But Now a formula occur bit long which my regex could not parse. formula looks like
**(U2+W2)/2*1000/W25**

This is my code which parse formula and iterate in cell address

```
string regex = @"\$?[A-Z]{1,3}\$?[0-9]{1,7}";
string strDefaultCalculations="(U2+W2)/2*1000/W25";

List<string> lstAddress = Regex.Matches(strDefaultCalculations, regex).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList();

foreach (var data in lstAddress)
{

}
```

Please some one suggest any changed RegEx as a result it can extract all cell address from this formula **(U2+W2)/2*1000/W25**. cell address would be U2, W2, W25.

also changed regex should be parse my others formula too means these formula below which are being parsed properly.

> a) (W2/R2)-1
> b) W23-U23

Please some one help me. i stuck very badly for my RegEx. thanks

Comment: With Excel Interop this can be easily achieved, the Range has a Precedents property which contains the formula precedents, U2, W2 and W25 in your case. But EPPlus doesn't have Precedents as far as I know, so I just added the EPPlus and RegEx tags to your question.

Comment: Your *real* problem is how to get the *dependent fields* from a formula, not how to parse it. Besides, Excel formulas and addresses are far more complex than what you posted. What if there are more than 25 columns?

Comment: EPPlus can parse and execute formulas so it [already includes a FormulaParser](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/blob/master/EPPlus/FormulaParsing/FormulaParser.cs)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos EPPlus can return all cell address used in formula that is what i am looking for. if you know then please share relevant code sample or links.

Comment: Based on the description of the `FormulaParser.Parse` method it just returns _The result of the calculation_ which means it returns the result of the formula `(U2+W2)/2*1000/W25`. Because EPPlus doesn't have `Precedents` implemented, try the following simple regex: `[A-Z]+\\d+` which should match all the upper case letters followed by number. Whole line of your code would be then: `List<string> lstAddress = Regex.Matches(yourCell.Formula, "[A-Z]+\\d+").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList();` HTH